# In Rails 3: Can a template image be associated with the view that's being displayed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Sorry, I'm very new at Rails so I'll try to be as specific as I can be.

In my template I have a large "header" style image. I would like to swap that image out for another image that is associated with the view that is being displayed. Maybe this can be done using a helper? I don't even know where to begin with this.

I know I could make a bunch of template pages and load each of them with the desired view, but I think thats a lot of repeated lines of code to load when I simply want to swap one image. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options depending on your needs. The first thing that comes to my head is to create a couple of helper methods. One to call from your custom views and one to call from your global layout.

For example, create a file `app/helpers/layout_helper.rb`

```
module LayoutHelper
  def header_image_tag
    @header_image ||= 'whatever-my-default-image-is.png'
    image_tag @header_image
  end

  def header_image(image_path)
    @header_image = image_path
  end
end
```

In your layout file... e.g `app/views/application.html.erb`. Something like:

```
<div id='banner'>
  <%= header_image_tag %>
</div>
```

In your individual view files that you don't want the default image:

```
<% header_image 'other-image.png' %>
```

That should get you started. You may want to allow the `header_image_tag` to take some options to pass onto the image_tag, or set some defaults that can be overridden.

The other thing you can take advantage of is `content_for` and `yield` blocks.

Example... in your custom views, you could put something like this at the top of your view:

```
<% content_for :banner do %>
  <%= image_tag 'blah.png' %>
<% end %>
```

And in your layout

```
<div id='banner'>
  <%= yield :banner || image_tag 'my-default.png' %>
</div>
```

Comment: I found an error with the code you posted for the first method. In the layout file... e.g app/views/application.html.erb you called <%= header_image %> when it needed to be <%= header_image_tag %> other wise perfect code. Thanks for the Help!

Comment: Thanks, it is now updated in the answer. I changed the way I wanted to call the helper method midstream. Normally this would have been done with tests ;-)

Comment: Do you know if there's a way I could do this but swapping in a flash object? I figured out how to manipulate this idea and use script instead of an image, but "sanitize" doesn't seem to play nice with the object tag

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "flash object". If you are having problems with a string inside of erb tags getting sanitized when you don't want it to... don't sanitize it. For Rails3 you can use html_safe or something like <%= raw your_object_tag %>.